# How to catch events and do console.log output in such a JavaScript example?

Tags: javascript, html

I came across one project, this is a browser port of the Space Cadet game that we all played on Windows XP
Example here https://alula.github.io/SpaceCadetPinball/
So this is the essence of the task, I need to hang up `console.log("Sound");` for each sound emitted by the game.
Or events when, for example, a ball bounces off walls or triggers or everything else
I just don't get where the logic is.
Here is the js code for the game:
https://alula.github.io/SpaceCadetPinball/SpaceCadetPinball.js
And this is the same code, only beautify
https://pastebin.com/DnsJ8wv3

I find this on line 5297, but removing it still the sound remains, it does not affect!

```
audioPlugin["handle"] = function audioPlugin_handle(byteArray, name, onload, onerror) {
        var done = false;

        function finish(audio) {
            if (done) return;
            done = true;
            Module["preloadedAudios"][name] = audio;
            if (onload) onload(byteArray)
        }

        function fail() {
            if (done) return;
            done = true;
            Module["preloadedAudios"][name] = new Audio;
            if (onerror) onerror()
        }
        if (Browser.hasBlobConstructor) {
            try {
                var b = new Blob([byteArray], {
                    type: Browser.getMimetype(name)
                })
            } catch (e) {
                return fail()
            }
            var url = Browser.URLObject.createObjectURL(b);
            var audio = new Audio;
            audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
                finish(audio)
            }, false);
            audio.onerror = function audio_onerror(event) {
                if (done) return;
                console.log("warning: browser could not fully decode audio " + name + ", trying slower base64 approach");

                function encode64(data) {
                    var BASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
                    var PAD = "=";
                    var ret = "";
                    var leftchar = 0;
                    var leftbits = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        leftchar = leftchar << 8 | data[i];
                        leftbits += 8;
                        while (leftbits >= 6) {
                            var curr = leftchar >> leftbits - 6 & 63;
                            leftbits -= 6;
                            ret += BASE[curr]
                        }
                    }
                    if (leftbits == 2) {
                        ret += BASE[(leftchar & 3) << 4];
                        ret += PAD + PAD
                    } else if (leftbits == 4) {
                        ret += BASE[(leftchar & 15) << 2];
                        ret += PAD
                    }
                    return ret
                }
                audio.src = "data:audio/x-" + name.substr(-3) + ";base64," + encode64(byteArray);
                finish(audio)
            };
            audio.src = url;
            Browser.safeSetTimeout(function() {
                finish(audio)
            }, 1e4)
        } else {
            return fail()
        }
    };
    Module["preloadPlugins"].push(audioPlugin);
```

Comment: What does "hang up `console.log("Sound");`" mean?

Comment: So that when playing each sound, output to the console what sound it was (if possible)
For example
`console.log("Sound1");
 console.log("Sound2"); 
console.log("Sound3");`

Comment: Please include a [mre] and explain specifically what about the code you are sharing you do not understand or otherwise need help with. Questions must stand on their own, without requiring answerers to navigate to another site in order to provide a complete answer.

Comment: I wrote clearly, I want to find in the code the logic that is responsible for playing this or that sound in the game, and so that when playing each sound, output logging in the console.log. The game has not one sound but several different ones. It is possible to output to the console for example Sound1 Sound2 Sound3 and so on.